# Getting @BeforeMethod setUp org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unhandled inspector error:

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting following error while running the script. It launches the browser but does not open the weblink.
I am using following version :

Chrome Driver version : 2.33.506120
Chrome browser version : 62.0.3202.62
Selenium version : 3.5.3
Testng : 6.11

Error is mentioned below :

> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp
>       org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}
>         (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.62)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Your error is clear: "Cannot navigate to invalid URL". What is the url?

Comment: I used www.freecrm.com

Answer (score 0):

Your error is clear:

```
Cannot navigate to invalid URL
```

from your comment, your url is `"www.freecrm.com"`.

Try adding "http://" before:

```
http://www.freecrm.com/
```

Comment: Tried but that didn't work. Still getting the same error

Comment: But your URL is correct? If I try to reach the page, I get a "Not found". Maybe is this? https://www.freecrm.com/login.cfm